Mis botones solo funcionan en la primera fila de la tabla
Tengo una tabla con unos botones en una columna llamada ENVIAR DATOS pero estos botones funciona solo en la primera fila. no se si hay algún problema con la función a la hora de tomar el id o algo así, solo la primera fila es la que funciona

Cuando se presionan los botones pueden copiar los datos la portapapeles o puede que envie por whatsapp una informacion especifica. la situación es que no consigo que funcione en las demás filas.
Este es el controlador de esta vista
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\Subscription;
use App\Models\Service;
use App\Models\Movement;
use App\Models\Payment;
use App\Models\Customer;
use Auth;
use Session;
use App\Helpers\Helper;
use App\Models\Profile;

class SubscriptionController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $title = "Suscripciones";

        $columns = [
            [
                'title'=>'Servicio',
                'key'=>'service_id',
                'type'=>'relation',
                'data'=>[
                    'relation'=>'service',
                    'key'=>'image_name',
                    'format'=>'html'
                ]
            ],
            [
                'title'=>'Cuenta',
                'key'=>'account_id',
                'type'=>'relation',
                'data'=>[
                    'relation'=>'account',
                    'key'=>'email',
                ]
            ],
            [
                'title'=>'Perfil',
                'key'=>'profile_id',
                'type'=>'relation',
                'data'=>[
                    'relation'=>'profile',
                    'key'=>'name',
                ]
            ],
            [
                'title'=>'Cliente',
                'key'=>'customer_id',
                'type'=>'relation',
                'data'=>[
                    'relation'=>'customer',
                    'key'=>'name',
                ]
            ],
            [
                'title'=>'Dias Restantes',
                'key'=>'last_days'
            ],
            [
                'title'=>'Vence',
                'key'=>'date_to',
                'type'=>'date',
                 'data'=>[
                    'format'=>'d-m-Y'
                 ]
            ],
            [
                'title'=>'Enviar Datos',
                'key'=>'share_buttons',
                'type'=>'html'
            ],
            [
                'title'=>'Estado',
                'key'=>'real_status',
                'type'=>'html'
            ]
        ];

        $data = Subscription::all();

        return view('admin.subscriptions.browse', compact('title','columns', 'data'));
    }
    public function create()
    {
        $title = "Nueva Suscripción";
        $type = "new";
        $services = Service::all();
        $customers = Customer::all();
        return view('admin.subscriptions.add-edit', compact('title','type','services','customers'));
    }

    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'service_id'=>'required',
            'account_id'=>'required',
            'customer_id'=>'required',
            'profile_id'=>'required|numeric|min:1',
            'date_to'=>'required',
            'amount'=>'required'
        ]);

        $element = new Subscription();
        $element->service_id = $request->service_id;
        $element->account_id = $request->account_id;
        $element->customer_id = $request->customer_id;
        $element->profile_id = $request->profile_id;
        $element->date_to = $request->date_to;
        $element->user_id = Auth::user()->id;

        if($element->save()){
            $payment = new Payment();
            $payment->customer_id = $element->customer_id;
            $payment->amount = $request->amount;
            if($payment->save()){
                $mvd = [
                    'type'=>'input',
                    'description'=>'Se Creo la suscripcion al servicio '.$element->service->name." de la cuenta con el correo ".$element->account->email.' para el cliente '.$element->customer->name,
                    'amount'=>$request->amount
                ];
                Movement::createMovement($mvd);
            }
            Session::flash('success', 'Registro Insertado con Exito!!');
        }else{
            Session::flash('error', 'Ocurrio un error al tratar de insertar el Registro!!');
        }

        return redirect()->route('subscriptions.index');
    }

    public function show(string $id)
    {

    }

    public function edit(string $id)
    {

    }

    public function update(Request $request, string $id)
    {

    }

    public function destroy(string $id)
    {
        $subscription = Subscription::find($id);
        if($subscription->delete()){
            Session::flash('success','Registro Eliminado con Exito!!');
        }else{
            Session::flash('error','Ocurrio un error al tratar de eliminar al Registro!!');
        }
        return redirect()->route('subscriptions.index');
    }

    public function getAccounts($service_id){
        $data = [];
        $attr = [
            'table'=>'accounts',
            'columns'=>[
                'id',
                'email'
            ],
            'compare'=>'service_id',
            'compare_value'=>$service_id
        ];
        $response = Helper::getDataSelect($attr,auth()->user()->id);
        if($response){
            $data = $response;
        }

        return response()->json(['data'=>$data]);
    }

    public function getProfiles($account_id){
        $data = [];
        $attr = [
            'table'=>'profiles',
            'columns'=>[
                'id',
                'name',
                'pin'
            ],
            'compare'=>'account_id',
            'compare_value'=>$account_id
        ];
        $response = Helper::getDataSelect($attr);
        if($response){
            foreach($response as $res){
                $profile = Profile::find($res->id);
                if($profile->subscriptions->count() == 0){
                    array_push($data, $res);
                }
            }
        }

        return response()->json(['data'=>$data]);
    }

    public function extend_subscriptions(Request $request){
        $sub = Subscription::findorfail($request->id);
        $sub->date_to = $request->date_to;
        if($sub->update()){
            $payment = new Payment();
            $payment->customer_id = $sub->customer_id;
            $payment->amount = $request->amount;
            if($payment->save()){
                $mvd = [
                    'type'=>'input',
                    'description'=>'Se extendio la suscripcion al servicio '.$sub->service->name." de la cuenta con el correo ".$sub->account->email.' para el cliente '.$sub->customer->name,
                    'amount'=>$request->amount
                ];
                Movement::createMovement($mvd);
            }
            Session::flash('success','Suscripcion Extendida con Exito!!');
        }else{
            Session::flash('error','Error al extender la Membresia!!');
        }

        return redirect()->route('subscriptions.index');
    }
}

Este es mi model donde están los botones
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Casts\Attribute;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use App\Scopes\ByUserScope;

class Subscription extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $table = 'subscriptions';
    protected $appends = ['last_days','real_status','share_buttons', 'mis_accounts'];

    protected static function booted()
    {
        static::addGlobalScope(new ByUserScope);
    }

    public function lastDays(): Attribute
    {
        return Attribute::make(
            get: fn ($value) => $this->getDays()
        );
    }

    public function realStatus(): Attribute
    {
        return Attribute::make(
            get: fn ($value) => $this->getRealStatus()
        );
    }

    public function customer(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Customer');
    }

    public function account(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Account');
    }

    public function service(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Service');
    }

    public function profile(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Profile');
    }

    public function getDays(){
        $now = time();
        $your_date = strtotime($this->date_to);
        $datediff =  $your_date - $now;
        $total = round($datediff / (60 * 60 * 24));
        if($total == 0){
            $total = 1;
        }

        if($total == -1){
            $total = 0;
        }
        return $total;
    }

    public function getRealStatus(){
        if($this->status == 0){
            return "<span class='badge badge-danger'>Inactivo</span>";
        }else{
            if($this->last_days <= 0){
                return "<span class='badge badge-warning'>Vencido</span>";
            }else{
                return "<span class='badge badge-success'>Activo</span>";
            }
        }
    }

    public function shareButtons(): Attribute
    {
        return Attribute::make(
            get: fn ($value) => $this->getShareButtons()
        );
    }

    public function getShareButtons(){
        $buttons = "<a href='#' id='send-by-whatsapp' data-id='".$this->id."' data-phone='".$this->customer->phone."' class='btn btn-success'><i class='fab fa-whatsapp'></i></a> <a href='#' class='btn btn-default' data-id='".$this->id."' id='copy_button'><i class='fas fa-copy'></i></a>";
        return $buttons;
    }

}

esta es mi vista blade
@extends('adminlte::page')

@section('title', $title)

@section('content')
    <div class="row" style="margin-top:20px;">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="card card-success">
                <div class="card-header">
                    <h2><i class="fas fa-star"></i> {{ $title }}</h2>
                </div>
                <div class="card-body" id="myTabContentEdit">
                    @include('admin.partials.table',['columns'=>$columns, 'data'=>$data, 'route'=>'subscriptions'])
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="modal fade" id="modal-extend">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title" id="staticBackdropLabel">Extender la Suscripción</h5>
            <button type="button" class="close close-modal-extend" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
              <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
          </div>
          <form action="{{route('extend_subscriptions')}}" method="POST">
            @method('PUT')
            @csrf
              <div class="modal-body">
                <input type="hidden" name="id" />
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="">Valor de la Suscripción:</label>
                    <input type="number" step="0.01" name="amount" required class="form-control" />
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="">Nueva Fecha vencimiento:</label>
                    <input type="date" name="date_to" required class="form-control" />
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" id="save-modal-extend"><i class="fas fa-save"></i> Extender</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger close-modal-extend"><i class="fas fa-times"></i> Cancelar</button>
              </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
@stop

@section('js')
    @include('admin.partials.messages')
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){

            $.ajaxSetup({
                headers: {
                    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': '{{ csrf_token() }}'
                }
            });

            $("a.btn-info").addClass('btn-warning').attr("title","Extender Facturacion").html('<i class="fas fa-external-link-alt"></>');
            $("a.btn-info").click(function(){
                let id = $(this).attr("data-id");
                $("input[name='id']").val(id);
                $("#modal-extend").modal({backdrop: 'static', keyboard:false},'show');
                return false;
            });

            $("button.close-modal-extend").click(function(){
                $("#modal-extend").modal('hide');
            });

            $("#copy_button").click(function(){
                let id = $(this).attr("data-id");
                $.get("get-data-message/"+id, function(response){
                    let data = response;
                    if(data.success){
                        copyToClipboard(data.message);
                        Swal.fire({
                            title: "Notificacion",
                            text: "Se han copiado los datos correctamente!!",
                            icon: "success",
                            position: "center",
                            showConfirmButton: false,
                            timer: 2000
                        });
                    }else{
                        Swal.fire({
                            title: "Notificacion",
                            text: data.messasge,
                            icon: "error"
                        });
                    }
                });
            });

            $("#send-by-whatsapp").click(function(){
                let id = $(this).attr("data-id");
                let phone = $(this).attr("data-phone");
                $.get("get-data-message/"+id, function(response){
                    let data = response;
                    if(data.success){
                        let link = encodeURI("https://wa.me/"+phone+"?text="+data.message);
                        window.open(link, "_blank");
                    }else{
                        Swal.fire({
                            title: "Notificacion",
                            text: data.messasge,
                            icon: "error"
                        });
                    }
                });
            });

            function copyToClipboard(text) {
                var $temp = $("<textarea></textarea>");
                $("#myTabContentEdit").append($temp);
                $temp.val(text).select();
                document.execCommand('copy');
                $temp.remove();
            }
        });
    </script>
@stop


Suena a un error clásico: los id deben ser únicos en el DOM. No descartes que ese sea el problema.
